# Where is the source code of dependencies in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm a beginner in typescript and npm, so my question may look stupid.
I declared some dependencies in my `package.json` file, and I have run the npm install command. Many dependencies were installed into the `node_modules` directory. But I think there should be the source code and doc in every dependency like that in java. But when I check the dependencies in `node_modules`, I only see the class declarations in some packages:

```
import { PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { JhiFilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
export declare class JhiPureFilterPipe extends JhiFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(input: Array<any>, filter: string, field: string): any;
}
```

There is no source code, neither the doc. So I was wondering where is the source code or even the compiled js code in these typescript package?

In java, when I declare dependencies in pom, I would see the source code of the API and their doc, but not the case for packages in node_modules.

Am I doing sth wrong?

Give me some hints plz!

Comment: That **is** the source.  Keep looking at the `from 'whereever';` in your `node_modules`.  Some files can be very lean only serving to pull in bigger dependencies.  Look at the file relative to the one you have shown at `./filter.pipe`.  That will likely be bigger.  Also, there may be no documentation included.

Answer (score 4):

All packages are different, but to find where the main code is, you need to look at the `package.json` file. Within that file you will find a `main` key which will tell you where the entry point is for that package (the path is relative to the `package.json` file):

```
{
  "name": "@angular/core",
  "version": "8.0.0-rc.0+354.sha-4809382.with-local-changes",
  "description": "Angular - the core framework",
  "main": "./bundles/core.umd.js"
}
```

If you navigate to that file you will see the entry point source code for that package. For the package you provided, [the source is here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/core-builds/master/bundles/core.umd.js)